# length not work with jquery mobile?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

(I use Jquery mobile and Phonegap).

I am trying to insert rows into the database, but I want to insert if the contained is not empty. this is my code below

```
for (var i = 0; i < id_textarea_commenter.length ; i++)
         {                
           var sql ="INSERT INTO Commenter (IdPrestation, IdTypeCommentaire, IdGroupe,  Commentaire,  rowguid)" +
                    "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

           Commentaire        =$('textarea#'+id_textarea_commenter[i]+'').val();
           IdTypeCommentaire  =id_textarea_commenter[i];


           if(  (Commentaire!= " ") || (Commentaire!= "") || (Commentaire.length!= 0) ) 
               {
                  console.log(Commentaire   +"--------"+ IdTypeCommentaire );
               params = [IdPrestation,IdTypeCommentaire, IdGroupe, Commentaire, rowguid];
               tx_commenter.executeSql(sql, params);
               console.log("I= "+i);
               }

          }
```

I am trying to insert rows into the database, but I want to insert if the contained is not empty. this is my code below

the problem even an insert fields is empty!

how I should solve this problem and thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use && not ||

```
if(  (Commentaire!= " ") && (Commentaire!= "") && (Commentaire.length!= 0) )
```

Depending on your page, you may need to check `Commentaire != undefined` too